# .NET CICD in Monorepo - Tips on how to structure the build, test, package stage(s)?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

How should I setup a basic Azure Devops CICD pipeline, given a mono repo that has projects for a web ui and a handful of service fabric service projects?
I want the ability to build once, then run a test command with a filter to only specific unit tests.
The rest of the tests need to be run once everything is deployed to an environment (later stages of the pipeline).
I am unusure how to structure the build, package and test step(s)

I have a good idea of what I need to end up with, but not sure quite how to get there in Azure Devops, and not sure if things like DotNetCoreCLI task, with a "test" command, will use existing dlls in the pipeline, or will build those projects again in order to test them?

The result I want after the "commit" stage is a drop that contains a folder per entity (UI, Service, etc.) where each folder contains everything needed to host/deploy that specific item.

I can work out how to iterate over those folders and actually deploy as necessary, I'm just stuck on what I should actually build?
My options as I see it:

1. Single All.sln that contains every project (along with their references)
2. csproj files of the specific deliverables (assuming all their references will also get build and included in the output)
3. Each csproj and sfproj in isolation and some way to group together everything that I need in the deployment folders

I do want to build/deploy all aspects of the system on a given run of the CICD pipeline.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the answers helpful to you? Please check the answer, if it is correct, please check it as a correct one. And if you have any question,we are willing to help you.